# scaling images for android different screen resolutions

Tags: android, android-layout

I am making an android app but the problem here is that there are dozens of android phones with different screen resolutions. So now I do not know which image sizes should I use. Is there a way to use one image and then android will scale it accordingly to screen resolution? If yes then which image size would be better?

Comment: You might want to read this: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes even if you use only single image in drawable folder, Android system will resize it for all devices, but ofcourse with images distortion. Well you should only bother about Drawable-hdpi, mdpi, ldpi and x-hdpi folders and place images respectively into it. Which differs in sizes. And best one is to use MDPI.

Its hard to understand, what i am suggested above, if you haven't read about [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html)

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html